# Breeze compatible SPA building

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js, kendo-ui, breeze

I am so impressed with Breeze that I decided to start collecting JavaScript frameworks / libraries which are Breeze compatible like http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/breezeknockout-template for example. However, simplifying JavaScript UI using the MVVMM pattern (Knockout contribution) is not all I need, as I would really like to use **KendoUI** for it's UI widgets and support for ASP.NET MVC.

As far as I can tell, KendoUI integration with Breeze is less than complete, because KendoUI DataSource component does not have to ability to handle Breeze Metadata so the best parts of Breeze are not utilized.

The other way of asking my question is this: can I build a JavaScript desktop application (SPA like entity) using Breeze for world class database access and some other JavaScript toolkit that offers world class UI builder?

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question!  We haven't yet created a binding library specifically for Kendo but we have received similar questions in the past.  In general, we use the [Breeze User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions) to prioritize our work on integration projects like this. So please add your voice. We take this venue seriously.

The other alternative is to contact Kendo and let them know of your interest. We would be very willing to cooperate/coordinate with them.  It's always easier if we have someone on the other side of the fence to work with.

Comment: I would be more than happy to help connecting my two favorite vendors as I do have some strong connections at Telerik as well as with IdeaBlade (check with Derick C. or Michael D.)

Comment: Jay, can you please contact me by email as I have several ideas on how to get this task moving to a good conclusion and would like to discuss them with you before moving ahead.

Comment: Take a look at **[kendo-labs/breeze-kendo](https://github.com/kendo-labs/breeze-kendo)** on github. Good folks at Kendo and in the community are working on this. I wish that I had more time for it myself.