# Breeze compatible JavaScript GUI frameworks

Tags: entity-framework, angularjs, extjs, breeze, wakanda

**While I already posted a similar question** ([Breeze compatible SPA building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504911/breeze-compatible-spa-building)) and likely started something good going between IdeaBlade and Telerik as a consequence, I believe that Breeze deserves a lot wider recognition because of its unique approach to access Entity Framework on the server side. So, it seems pretty obvious to me that even notoriously complete JS frameworks like **Sencha** or **Wakanda** *need to ensure to work with Breeze*.

The current issues between KendoUI and Breeze are very clearly described in the post by Remco Blok at http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/13-02-21/breeze_js_and_the_kendo_ui_datasource.aspx. Stated succinctly the integration with Breeze should be made at the level of entities - not JSON data, which is the way almost everyone handles the transactions between a JS client and SQL server.

Wakanda is a great example of a very rich development environment with elaborate GUI Builder, Debugger etc that unfortunately cannot be used with "legacy data" on the server side.

As far as I know, Breeze works just fine with Angular, but Angular needs AngularUI (http://angular-ui.github.io/) which in turn is not as complete as I would like it to be and has some JQuery dependencies that may cause collisions. Pretty soon, Breeze will work with KendoUI (AFAIK) - does anyone know about some other collection of JavaScript frameworks that all together would offer the level of ease that Visual Studio provides for Windows desktop applications creation? (after all, JavaScript applications are desktop application with the distribution problem solved in a very elegant fashion).

Comment: As of Wakanda 8 you can use ODBC which should open up many possibilities for accessing legacy data.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a lot of success using [breeze](http://www.breezejs.com/) with [durandal](http://durandaljs.com/), [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/).  Each of these frameworks kind of stick to their own responsibiliities- breeze for data, durandal for app plumbing, bootstrap for ui scaffolding and knockout for data-binding.  This has proven to be pretty flexible and simplistic.

Comment: Sorry for adding this comment so late - I must have missed Stackoverflow notification.

My point is that KendoUI seems to offer the richest GUI layer - while there is no support for using it with Angular and Breeze "touple". My choice of Angular and Breeze as the key building blocks, leaves me without a sufficiently good GUI component.